# how to integrate external js resource in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

hi i am very new to thymeleaf now i am trying to include

**line no:5**

**but i am getting error like**

i have try like this

```
<div xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
     layout:decorator="layout" layout:fragment="content">

<head>
    <title>Google Address Loopup Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-latest.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-latest.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        /*$('#selected').text("Place selected:" +place.formatted_address)*/
        });
        });
    </script>



</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50"/>
</div>

<!--<div id="selected">No address selected</div>-->
</body>
</div>
```

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="test", line 5 - column 103

and the line number five is the script code which i have pasted above.
can any one help me for this 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape `& , < , > and "` characters. Try this address:
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false`